# Split Python Array based on a property

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a Python List like this:

```
myList = [
    {
        "key": 1,
        "date": "2020-01-02"
    },
    {
        "key": 2,
        "date": "2020-02-02"
    },
    {
        "key": 3,
        "date": "2020-01-03"
    },
    {
        "key": 4,
        "date": "2020-01-02"
    },
    {
        "key": 5,
        "date": "2020-02-02"
    },
]
```

Now I want to split the array based on the property "date". I want my list to look like this

```
myList = [
    [
        {
            "key": 1,
            "date": "2020-01-02"
        },
        {
            "key": 4,
            "date": "2020-01-02"
        },
    ],
    [
        {
            "key": 2,
            "date": "2020-02-02"
        },
        {
            "key": 5,
            "date": "2020-02-02"
        },
    ],
    [
        {
            "key": 3,
            "date": "2020-01-03"
        },
    ]
]
```

So I want a new array for each specific date in the current list. Can someone help me to achieve that?

Comment: What have you tried yourself? You're grouping by some attribute of the list elements, do you need to use a list of dictionaries and a list of lists of dictionaries, or have you considered other data structures that would make this operation a lot easier like dataframes?

Comment: I tried something with loops but I don't like it. I haven't used any other data structures but anything that helps could be good

Comment: That first list of dictionaries looks like would make more sense as a dictionary itself... assuming the keys are guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: Do the keys represent anything besides the order in which those items were added to the original list? Is it possible to have holes or out-of-order keys, or is it always 1, 2, 3, 4...? If the former, you basically just have a list of dates, with additional nesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
d={}
for i in range(len(myList)):
    d.setdefault(myList[i]['date'], []).append(i) 
myList = [ [myList[i] for i in v] for k,v in d.items() ]  # replace the original `myList` following PO behavior.
```

#### Logic:

You want to group the data based on 'date' that means you need a `dictionary` data structure. The rest are just implementation details.

Comment: It is generous to give a UP-vote also. As it helps others to see it and also a reward to the author as compensation for energy and time.  Yeah, sure, only if you think the answer is good. LoL